# Integrate Bot framework with UWP

Tags: uwp, botframework

Hello could anyone teach how to integrate bot with Uwp?, i want create a APP by using uwp, to allow user to check weather and news, but i don't know how to integrate Uwp and Bot together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a UWP app with Bot Framework by following this example code:
https://github.com/ActiveNick/BotFrameworkTestClient

For more information, check out the article: [Create a UWP-Based ChatBot Using the Microsoft Bot Framework Direct Line API](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/01/01/create-a-uwp-based-chatbot.aspx)

You will also find some help in this video walkthrough: [Channel 9 - Microsoft Bot Framework with Xamarin and UWP](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Windows-Dev/Microsoft-Bot-Framework-with-Xamarin-and-UWP)